# kafka + what is the meaning of Log directory is offline

Tags: apache-kafka, disk

our Kafka production cluster include **23 broker machines** , and each broker include **35** JBOD disks

broker version is - apache 2.7 version , and cluster include 5 zookeeper servers

from `/var/log/kafka/server.log` we seen many warning like the following

```
Log directory /var/kafka/broker_logsXX is offline
```

or here are few examples from `server.log`

```
[2023-09-22 02:10:34,583] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=1012] Unable to describe replica dirs for /var/kafka/broker_logs3 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Log directory /var/kafka/broker_logs3 is offline
[2023-09-22 02:10:34,588] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=1012] Unable to describe replica dirs for /var/kafka/broker_logs24 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Log directory /var/kafka/broker_logs24 is offline
[2023-09-22 02:10:34,588] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=1012] Unable to describe replica dirs for /var/kafka/broker_logs9 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Log directory /var/kafka/broker_logs9 is offline
[2023-09-22 02:10:34,594] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=1012] Unable to describe replica dirs for /var/kafka/broker_logs39 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Log directory /var/kafka/broker_logs39 is offline





[2023-11-03 09:52:46,390] INFO Updated cache from existing <empty> to latest FinalizedFeaturesAndEpoch(features=Features{}, epoch=1). (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureCache)
[2023-11-03 09:52:46,393] INFO Cluster ID = XXXXXXXXXXX (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2023-11-03 09:52:46,724] ERROR Fail to read meta.properties under log directory /var/kafka/broker_logs24 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/kafka/broker_logs24/meta.properties.tmp: Input/output error
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:244)
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
        at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
        at kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint.read(BrokerMetadataCheckpoint.scala:69)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.$anonfun$getBrokerMetadataAndOfflineDirs$1(KafkaServer.scala:784)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.$anonfun$getBrokerMetadataAndOfflineDirs$1$adapted(KafkaServer.scala:782)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.getBrokerMetadataAndOfflineDirs(KafkaServer.scala:782)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:246)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

not clearly why Kafka broker is complains about  Log directory `/var/kafka/....` is offline ?

is it because disk problem ? or high load on disk ? or maybe broker not sync to target replica ? , etc.

on the last example we can see

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /var/kafka/broker_logs24/meta.properties.tmp: Input/output error
```

from my understanding `input/output` errors is maybe typical disk problem

but when I look on all 35 broker machine we can see about 4-6 warning about  `Log directory /var/kafka/... is offline`

so its not make sense that each broker has 4-6 faulty disks ?

Comment: You can use commands like `fsck` to check disk health